# Bash, retrieving two sets of particular strings from across a text file

Tags: bash

consider the example:

```
Feb 14 26:00:01 randomtext here mail from user10@mailbox.com more random text
Feb 15 25:08:82 randomtext random text mail from user8@mailbox.com more random text
Jan 20 26:23:89 randomtext iortest test test mail from user6@mailbox.com more random
Mar 15 18:23:01 randomtext here mail from user4@mailbox.com more random text
Jun 15 20:04:01 randomtext here mail from user10@mailbox.com more random text
```

Using BASH I am trying to retrieve the first part of the time stamp for example '26' '25' and the email of the user for example 'user10@mailbox.com'

output would then roughly look like:

```
26 user10@mailbox.com
25 user8@mailbox.com
26 user6@mailbox.com
18 user4@mailbox.com
20 user10@mailbox.com
```

I have tried using:

```
cat myfile | grep -o '[0-9][0-9].*.com'
```

but it gives me excess text in the middle. 
How would i go about retrieving just the two strings i need?

Comment: [Useless Use Of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) spotted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed` with capture groups to select the parts you want.

```
sed 's/^.* \([0-9][0-9]\):.* mail from \(.*@.*\.com\).*/\1 \2/' myfile
```

- `^` = beginning of line
- `.*` = any sequence of characters followed by space
- `\([0-9[0-9]\):` = 2 digits followed by a colon. The digits will be saved in capture group #1
- `.* mail from` = any sequence up to a space followed by `mail from` and another space
- `\(.*@.*\.com\)` = any sequence followed by `@` followed by any sequence up to `.com`. This will be saved in capture group #2
- `.*` = any sequence; this will match the rest of the line

Everything this matches (the whole line) will be replaced by capture group #1, a space, and capture group #2.

Comment: Could you give me a brief run down on how this code works? I'm fairly new to sed so I'm constantly having to look up stuff, thanks!

Comment: See edit, does it help? I think there's a web site where you can enter a regexp and it will explain it automatically, but I don't know the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cat myfile | awk '{print $3, $8}' | sed 's/:[0-9][0-9]//g'
```

Disclaimer: my `awk` skills are rusty - there should be a way to do this solely in `awk` without resorting to `sed`.

Comment: I suspect the email is not always in `$8`.

Comment: In fact, I'm sure of it. Look at the 2nd and 3rd lines of the file.

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -lne '
    print "$1 $2" if /^\w+\s+\d+\s+(\d+):\d+:\d+\s+.*?([-\w\.]+@\S+)/
' file.txt
```

Output :

```
26 0@mailbox.com
25 8@mailbox.com
26 6@mailbox.com
18 4@mailbox.com
20 0@mailbox.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your email-addresses will have only domain .com - the previous answer using sed is perfect.
But if you can have different domain, it's better to improve this sed:

```
sed 's/^.* \([0-9][0-9]\):.* mail from \(.*@.*\..*\)\ more.*/\1 \2/' file
```